# How to make only the top borders in every page

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, border

Can anyone let me know how to make only the top borders (not including the bottom borders) on each page, with some names written on the top of the borders? 
The top borders I mean looks like this, for example.
[image]

Comment: Take a look at the `fancyhdr` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done easily with the `fancyhdr` package. For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead[L]{Trinity Training 2011}
\fancyhead[C]{Power of a Point}
\fancyhead[R]{Yufei Zhao}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\centering
{\LARGE\bfseries Power of a Point}

{\Large\bfseries Solutions}

Yufei Zhao

Trinity College, Cambridge
\end{document}
```

[image]